# Criteria query combine and predicates and or predicates in where method

Tags: java, criteria-api

The `where` method of CriteriBuilder

> restricts the query result according to the conjunction of the specified restriction predicates

In other words, concatenate all predicates with AND. I pass a list of predicates to this method in this way:

```
criteria.where(preds.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
```

The result query is something like this:

```
... where p1 and p2 and p3
```

however what I need is:

```
... where p1 and p2 or p3
```

I tried to use two list of preds, one for "ANDS" and another one for "ORS":

```
if(preds.isEmpty() && !orPreds.isEmpty()) {
    criteria.where(cb.or(orPreds.toArray(new Predicate[orPreds.size()])));
}
else if(!preds.isEmpty() && !orPreds.isEmpty()) {
    criteria.where(cb.and(preds.toArray(new Predicate[preds.size()])), 
    cb.or(orPreds.toArray(new Predicate[orPreds.size()])));
}
else {
    criteria.where(preds.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
}
```

But the result query is the same:

```
... where p1 and p2 and p3
```

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by `where p1 and p2 or p3`? `where (p1 and p2) or p3`? `where p1 and (p2 or p3)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply combine your arrays of predicates into simple predicates, using [`CriteriaBuilder.and(Predicate... restrictions)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#and(javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...)) and [`CriteriaBuilder.or(Predicate... restrictions)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#or(javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...))

For getting `where (p1 and p2) or p3`, where `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are all arrays of predicates concatenated with `and` statements:

```
Predicate[] p1 = new Predicate[2];
Predicate[] p2 = new Predicate[2];
Predicate[] p3 = new Predicate[2];
// add your predicates to the arrays.     
Predicate p1all = cb.and(p1);    
Predicate p2all = cb.and(p2);
Predicate p3all = cb.and(p3);
Predicate pFinal = cb.or(cb.and(p1all, p2all), p3all);
criteria.where(pFinal);
```

For getting `where p1 and (p2 or p3)`:

```
Predicate pFinal = cb.and(cb.or(p2all, p3all), p1all);
criteria.where(pFinal);
```

Finally, if you want to build a single predicate by concatenating an array of predicates with `or` statements, use this:

```
Predicate p1all = cb.or(p1);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default all predicates are understood as "AND".

You can "play" adding more complexity to the predicates using cb.and / cb.or (nested if needed)

You can create a list like this:

```
Root<BeanA> queryRoot = cq.from(BeanA.class);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
predicates.add(cb.equal(queryRoot.get("id"), valueA);
predicates.add(cb.or(
                cb.equal(queryRoot.get("id"), valueA,
                cb.equal(queryRoot.get("id"), valueB
        ));
predicates.add(cb.and(
       cb.equal(queryRoot.get("valueC"), valueC),
       cb.or(
             cb.equal(queryRoot.get("id"), valueA,
             cb.equal(queryRoot.get("id"), valueB
        ))
);

cq.where(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
```

If needed, you can use a multiselect too (adding here the result of subqueries if you want to handle them)

```
 List<Selection> selectList = new ArrayList<>();

 selectList.add(queryRoot.get("id"));
 selectList.add(queryRoot.get("title"));

 cq.multiselect(selectList.toArray(Selection[]::new));
```

After adding a multiselect you could need an orderBy.
you can follow the same concept but using a Expression list

```
List<Expression> groupByList = new ArrayList<>();

groupByList.add(proyectoJoin.get("id"));
groupByList.add(proyectoJoin.get("title"));
 
cq.groupBy(groupByList.toArray(Expression[]::new));
```